# What is the terminal command to force the software center to update its installed lists?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, uninstall, deb, virtualization

Hello I have installed haroopad.deb (markdown editor) through the Software Center. After that the program can be found unity dash search and starts fine.  But the Software Center is unaware  of the haroopad package - no Unknown category in Installed and no history of the installation. I was wondering what is the terminal command to force the software center to update its installed lists?

OS:Ubuntu 15.10 64bit VM + guest additions

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I can confirm that this does not show in software centre, it is not in unknown or technical items but the program works fine. i will have a look but am a bit stumped, good question +1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)